# Replication of XGBoost's binary:logistic loss

Tags: xgboost, loss-function

I am trying to replicate XGBoost's logistic loss function as a first step before implementing my own custom loss functions. Following from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/konstantinpluzhnikov/tm-xgboost-custom-loss-for-binary-classification/notebook) and looking at the original code in [git repository](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/src/objective/regression_loss.h), I can deduct that the logistic loss first and second derivatives are given by:

```
def logloss(predt: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:

    def gradiant(p: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix) -> np.ndarray:
        y = dtrain.get_label()
        return p - y

    def hessian(p: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix) -> np.ndarray:
        y = dtrain.get_label()
        return p * (1 - p)


    predt[predt < -1] = -1 + 1e-6
    grad = gradiant(predt, dtrain)
    hess = hessian(predt, dtrain)
    return grad, hess
```

In order to have a comparable evaluation metric for the purpose of the exercise, I am also following from the post above and define the log-loss as an evaluation metric as well:

```
def logloss_metric(predt, dmat):

    y=dmat.get_label() if isinstance(dmat,xgb.DMatrix) else dmat
    predt=np.clip(predt,10e-7,1-10e-7)
    return 'logloss_myerror', - np.mean(y * np.log(predt) + (1-y) * np.log(1-predt))
```

I can then train two different model configurations, one with the default `binary:logistic` and one with my custom defined function, however both with the same evaluation metric. As follows:

```
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from typing import Tuple
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import pandas as pd

data = load_breast_cancer()
X = pd.DataFrame(data['data'], columns=data['feature_names'])
y = pd.DataFrame(data['target'])

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X, y, feature_names=X.columns)
```

```
clf0 = xgb.train({'tree_method': 'hist', 'seed': 1994, 'objective': 'binary:logistic', 'disable_default_eval_metric': 0},  # any other tree method is fine.
                 dtrain=dtrain,
                 num_boost_round=20,
                 maximize=False,
                 feval=logloss_metric,
                 evals=[(dtrain,'train')])
```

```
[0] train-error:0.02109 train-logloss_myerror:0.51087
[1] train-error:0.01055 train-logloss_myerror:0.07307
[2] train-error:0.00879 train-logloss_myerror:0.07185
[3] train-error:0.00527 train-logloss_myerror:0.06112
[4] train-error:0.00527 train-logloss_myerror:0.03483
[5] train-error:0.00527 train-logloss_myerror:0.03002
[6] train-error:0.00527 train-logloss_myerror:0.02753
[7] train-error:0.00527 train-logloss_myerror:0.02704
[8] train-error:0.00527 train-logloss_myerror:0.02697
[9] train-error:0.00527 train-logloss_myerror:0.02646
[10]    train-error:0.00527 train-logloss_myerror:0.02530
[11]    train-error:0.00527 train-logloss_myerror:0.00331
[12]    train-error:0.00527 train-logloss_myerror:0.00160
[13]    train-error:0.00176 train-logloss_myerror:0.00078
[14]    train-error:0.00176 train-logloss_myerror:0.00024
[15]    train-error:0.00176 train-logloss_myerror:0.00001
[16]    train-error:0.00000 train-logloss_myerror:0.00000
[17]    train-error:0.00000 train-logloss_myerror:0.00000
[18]    train-error:0.00000 train-logloss_myerror:0.00000
[19]    train-error:0.00000 train-logloss_myerror:0.00000
```

```
clf1 = xgb.train({'tree_method': 'hist', 'seed': 1994, 'disable_default_eval_metric': 0},  # any other tree method is fine.
                 dtrain=dtrain,
                 num_boost_round=20,
                 obj=logloss,
                 feval=logloss_metric,
                 maximize=False,
                 evals=[(dtrain,'train')])
```

```
[0] train-rmse:0.14949  train-logloss_myerror:0.10558
[1] train-rmse:0.13031  train-logloss_myerror:0.08458
[2] train-rmse:0.12824  train-logloss_myerror:0.08155
[3] train-rmse:0.12494  train-logloss_myerror:0.07799
[4] train-rmse:0.12487  train-logloss_myerror:0.07805
[5] train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07800
[6] train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
[7] train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
[8] train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
[9] train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
[10]    train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
[11]    train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
[12]    train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
[13]    train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
[14]    train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
[15]    train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
[16]    train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
[17]    train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
[18]    train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
[19]    train-rmse:0.12485  train-logloss_myerror:0.07801
```

At the first iterations, both of them have completely different evaluations, and although my model `clf1` seems to converge only after 3-4 iterations, it never reaches 0. I am posting the original code, as you can see the derivatives are the same. My classifier also seems to default the eval metric to rmse, which could mean that it recognizes the problem as a regression problem. Hence, I tried to also specify `booster:gbtree`, just in case. I have also tried to make `eval_metric:auc`, same thing happens. What is going on here?

```
struct LogisticRegression {
  XGBOOST_DEVICE static bst_float PredTransform(bst_float x) { return common::Sigmoid(x); }
  XGBOOST_DEVICE static bool CheckLabel(bst_float x) { return x >= 0.0f && x <= 1.0f; }
  XGBOOST_DEVICE static bst_float FirstOrderGradient(bst_float predt, bst_float label) {
    return predt - label;
  }
  XGBOOST_DEVICE static bst_float SecondOrderGradient(bst_float predt, bst_float) {
    const float eps = 1e-16f;
    return fmaxf(predt * (1.0f - predt), eps);
  }
```

**EDIT:**

I have modified the derivatives such that the prediction output is transformed with a sigmoid, as follows:

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def logloss(predt: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:

    def gradiant(p: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix) -> np.ndarray:
        p = sigmoid(p)
        y = dtrain.get_label()
        return p - y

    def hessian(p: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix) -> np.ndarray:
        p = sigmoid(p)
        y = dtrain.get_label()
        eps = 1e-16
        hess = p * (1 - p)
        hess[hess < eps] = eps
        return hess


    predt[predt < -1] = -1 + 1e-6
    grad = gradiant(predt, dtrain)
    hess = hessian(predt, dtrain)
    return grad, hess
```

This now works. Moreover, I have set up a native `eval_metric` just to be sure by passing it as an argument to `xgb.train`, in this case `eval_metric='logloss'`. To make sure that the problem does not get recognizes as a regression problem, I have set also `booster:gbtree`. Although this is now way closer to the native implementation and it actually converges, I still cannot match it and the convergence is not as smooth.

[image: convergence of XGBoost]